# How would I replace two or more blank lines with a single blank line in Ed?

Tags: regular-expression, ed

In Ed I can do a search to replace all blank lines as follows:

```
g/^$/d
```

This deletes all blank lines. But what if I wish to delete two or more blank lines and keep 1? For example:

```
Line 1


Line 2



Line 3
```

Becomes:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

Comment: Are all non-empty lines otherwise different from their immediate following line? If so, `e !uniq %` would be one solution... This requires you to first save your unsaved edits with `w` first though.

Comment: Interesting; tr can squeeze duplicate characters but a blank line to be left in requires two sequential newline characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapted from the [Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Best_Vim_Tips#Global_command):

```
ed -s file <<EOF
v/./.,/./-1j
w
q
EOF
```

- `v/./`: select all lines that don't match the regex `.` (i.e., select all blank lines). Execute the following action on them:

  - `.,/./-1j`: the `j`oin command is applied from a selected line (`.`) up to the the line above the next non-blank line (`/./-1`).
- `w q`: save and quit. You could use `%p Q` instead to only display the output without modifying the file.

---

Although equally valid, my original suggestion was more complicated:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^$/.,/./-1d\' 'i\' '' w q | ed -s file
```

This one uses two commands for a single `g`lobal command (usually the command list consists of a single command), which requires prefixing newlines with backslashes for its command list.

- `g/^$/`: select all blank lines.

  - `.,/./-1d\`: `d`elete from the selected line (`.`) up to the line above the next non-blank line (`/./-1`). This would delete all blank lines, so
  - `'i\' ''`: `i`nsert a new blank line above.

---

It is equivalent to use [here-docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) or Printf to feed Ed. Just pick the one you like best.

Reference: [POSIX Ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html).

Answer (score 3):

Using an external command is a totally valid way to edit in `ed`, and assuming that all non-empty lines are unique when compared to their immediately surrounding lines (i.e. non-repeating), we could call `uniq` to remove the excess empty lines:

```
w
e !uniq %
```

We need to save our work with `w` first since `uniq` will read from the current file on disk.  The `e !somecommand` command replaces the contents of the editing buffer with the output of `somecommand`, and `uniq` will remove duplicated consecutive lines in the named file. The `%` in the command will be replaced by the name of the current file. With our assumption at the start, this solves our issue by removing duplicated consecutive empty lines.

Comment: I don't see any assumption that the lines are not repeated. So if the file is a\na\n\n\nb\n unique will change this to a\n\nb\n so missing a whole a\n.

Comment: @icarus I made this assumption explicitly at the start: _assuming that all non-empty lines are unique when compared to their immediately surrounding lines_  Maybe I should change the wording to "not repeated"?

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the assumption in the OP post. I am down voting this answer as I don't want to scan a 20GB file by eye to see if there are repeated lines.

Comment: @icarus You're editing 20 GB files in `ed`?! You can scan that with `uniq` and `grep` first if you wish, instead of with your eyes: `uniq -d file | grep '.'` (if there's output, you need to go for a different solution).

Comment: I am partial to this solution for its simplicity.